# How to table data scraped from the web and read all the data from a table

Tags: r

I am trying to scrape data from the web, specifically from a table that has different filters and pages and I have the following code:

```
library (rvest)

url.colombia.compra <- "https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to = & date_from = "
tmp <- read_html (url.colombia.compra)
tmp_2 <- html_nodes (tmp, ".active")
```

the problem is that the code generates a list for me but I need to format it as a table and I have not succeeded, besides that it only shows me data from the first page of the table, how could I complement the code so that it allows me to read the data from all the pages in the table and format it as a table.

This is the table that looks like the table that shows the data

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split this problem into two parts. Your first is how to programmatically access each of the 11 pages of this online table.

Since this is a simple html table, using the "Next" button (siguiente) will take us to a new page. If we look at the URL on the Next page, we can see the page number in the query parameters.

> ...tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?**page=1**&number_order=&state...

We know that the pages are numbered starting with 0 (because "next" takes us to page1), and using the navigation bar we can see that there are 11 pages.

We can use the query parameters to construct a series of `rvest::read_html()` calls corresponding to page number by simply using lapply and paste0 to replace the `page=`. This will let us access all the pages of the table.

The second part is making use of `rvest::html_table` which will parse a tibble from the results of `read_html`

```
pages <-
  lapply(0:11, function(x) {
    data.frame(
      html_table(
        read_html(x = paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=", 
                             x, 
                             "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to_=%20&date_from_="))
      )
    )
        
  })
```

The result is a list of dataframes which we can combine with `do.call`.

```
do.call(rbind, pages)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!! en el momento de ejecutar código me aparece el siguente error:        colombiano/ordenes-compra?
Error: inesperado '>' in:
"                         x, 
                         "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")) |>"
>       html_table() |>
Error: inesperado '>' in "      html_table() |>"
>       data.frame()
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
>   })
Error: inesperado '}' in "  }"
> 
> do.call(rbind, pages)
Error in do.call(rbind, pages) : objeto 'pages'

Comment: It may be that the `|>` operator is not supported by your R version. You can nest the functions instead of using the native pipe. I made an edit to remove the use of the `|>` operator form the answer.